# Hide and Show div depending on class and id (Incrementally) of html tag in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

Currently I have multiple `select option` using `MDB` frontend framework

and I'm loading it with different `class, id and name`

this is the working code

```
 @if(count($manage_access_list))
                    @foreach($manage_access_list as $field)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                {{$field->access_desc}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select class="mdb-select accessSelect{{$field->id}}" name="accessSelect{{$field->id}}" id="accessSelect{{$field->id}}" style="width: 170px!important;">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
                                    <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
                                    <option value="NO">No Access</option>
                                    <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2 access-right{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add{{$field->id}}" name="add{{$field->id}}" id="add{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="add{{$field->id}}">Add</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 access-right{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit{{$field->id}}" name="edit{{$field->id}}" id="edit{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit{{$field->id}}">Edit</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 access-right{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove{{$field->id}}" name="remove{{$field->id}}" id="remove{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove{{$field->id}}">Remove</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
```

And this is my JS code

```
<script>
$("#accessSelect1").on('change', function() {
    if(this.value == "ALL"){
       $(".access-right1").hide();
    }
    else if (this.value == "NO"){
        $(".access-right1").hide();
    }
    else if(this.value == "CONFIG"){
        $(".access-right1").show();
    }
  });

  </script>
```

Output :

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the id for `select option` > `accessSelect1` is hard coded

What I'm trying to do is to show and hide specific `add,edit,remove` for each line. using the id of `select option` `accessSelect`

As of now, Show and Hide of div is working only for `accessSelect1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// [id^=accessSelect] will select all IDs starting with"accessSelect"
$("[id^=accessSelect]").on('change', function() { 
    // from the current select get the parent .row element
    // from there chose the child containing a class "access-right"
    var $accessRights = $(this).closest('.row').children('[class*=access-right]');
    if($(this).val() == "CONFIG") {
        $accessRights.show();
    } else {
       // if it's not "CONFIG" you want to hide them allways
       $accessRights.hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="mdb-select accessSelect1" name="accessSelect1" id="accessSelect1" style="width: 170px!important;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
            <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
            <option value="NO">No Access</option>
            <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
        </select>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 access-right1" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add1" name="add1" id="add1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="add1">Add</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right1" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit1" name="edit1" id="edit1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit1">Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right1" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove1" name="remove1" id="remove1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove1">Remove</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="mdb-select accessSelect2" name="accessSelect2" id="accessSelect2" style="width: 170px!important;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
            <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
            <option value="NO">No Access</option>
            <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
        </select>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 access-right2" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add1" name="add1" id="add1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="add1">Add</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right2" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit1" name="edit1" id="edit1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit1">Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right2" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove1" name="remove1" id="remove1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove1">Remove</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="mdb-select accessSelect3" name="accessSelect3" id="accessSelect3" style="width: 170px!important;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
            <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
            <option value="NO">No Access</option>
            <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
        </select>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 access-right3" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add1" name="add1" id="add1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="add1">Add</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right3" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit1" name="edit1" id="edit1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit1">Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right3" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove1" name="remove1" id="remove1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove1">Remove</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="mdb-select accessSelect4" name="accessSelect4" id="accessSelect4" style="width: 170px!important;">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
            <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
            <option value="NO">No Access</option>
            <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
        </select>
    </div>

        <div class="col-md-2 access-right4" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add1" name="add1" id="add1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="add1">Add</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right4" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit1" name="edit1" id="edit1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit1">Edit</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 access-right4" style="display:none;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove1" name="remove1" id="remove1">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove1">Remove</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RaeIan glad it helped, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Hope this will work

Declare `data-id = "{{$field->id}}"` on `select`

Add `access-right` class on `select`

```
@if(count($manage_access_list))
                    @foreach($manage_access_list as $field)
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                {{$field->access_desc}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select data-id = "{{$field->id}}" class="access-select mdb-select accessSelect{{$field->id}}" name="accessSelect{{$field->id}}" id="accessSelect-{{$field->id}}" style="width: 170px!important;">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
                                    <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
                                    <option value="NO">No Access</option>
                                    <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2" id="access-right-{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add{{$field->id}}" name="add{{$field->id}}" id="add-{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="add{{$field->id}}">Add</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2" id="access-right-{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit{{$field->id}}" name="edit{{$field->id}}" id="edit-{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit{{$field->id}}">Edit</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2" id="access-right-{{$field->id}}" style="display:none;">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove{{$field->id}}" name="remove{{$field->id}}" id="remove-{{$field->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove{{$field->id}}">Remove</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
```

```
<script>
$(".access-select").on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        if(this.value == "ALL"){
           $("#access-right-"+id).hide();
        }
        else if (this.value == "NO"){
            $("#access-right-"+id).hide();
        }
        else if(this.value == "CONFIG"){
            $("#access-right-"+id).show();
        }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: This gives me an idea

Comment: @RaeIan this can be solved without `data-id` attribute. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818971/2008111

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to replace your selector with class. Use the following script and html which will work just fine.

```
@if(count($manage_access_list))
    @foreach($manage_access_list as $field)
        <div class="row" id="accessSelect{{$field->id}}">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                {{$field->access_desc}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <select class="mdb-select accessSelect{{$field->id}}" name="accessSelect{{$field->id}}" style="width: 170px!important;">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Access Right</option>
                    <option value="ALL">All Access</option>
                    <option value="NO">No Access</option>
                    <option value="CONFIG">Config Access</option>
                </select>
            </div>

                <div class="col-md-2 access-check access-right-all" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input add{{$field->id}}" name="add{{$field->id}}" id="add{{$field->id}}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="add{{$field->id}}">Add</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 access-check access-right-no" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input edit{{$field->id}}" name="edit{{$field->id}}" id="edit{{$field->id}}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="edit{{$field->id}}">Edit</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 access-check access-right-config" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input remove{{$field->id}}" name="remove{{$field->id}}" id="remove{{$field->id}}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="remove{{$field->id}}">Remove</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The row will have unique id and based on that we will handle child components

```
$(".mdb-select").on('change', function() {
    var select = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#' + select + ' .access-check').hide();
    $('#' + select + ' .access-right-' + value.toLowerCase()).show();
});
```